# Redactor plugin not found: imagePosition Craft 3

Tags: redactor

I just updated a Craft 2 site to Craft 3, everything pretty much works except for this error:

```
Redactor plugin not found: imagePosition
```

Since Redactor is now installed via the plugin store, how do I go about rectifying this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you get the error is probably that you had the [Redactor Image Position plugin](https://github.com/picdorsey/craft-redactorimageposition) installed in Craft 2. If the plugin was available for Craft 3, you'd just need to update to it. But since it's not available, you're kinda out of luck.

To remove the error message though, you only need to remove `'imagePosition'` from the list of enabled plugins in your redactor config files, they're located at `config/redactor` and works the same as in Craft 2.